# SAML 2.0 implementation in .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, saml-2.0, enterprise

There are plenty of ways to implement SAML 2.0 authentication in C#.NET like Azure AD, OneLogin etc. I want to do SAML 2.0 authentication between my applications while they call each other. I went through https://developers.onelogin.com/saml/c-and-aspnet, any other way for such implementation ?

Comment: You could take a look at: [SAML2.AspNet](https://github.com/elerch/SAML2/tree/master/src/SAML2.AspNet) and [Owin.Security.Saml](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Owin.Security.Saml/)

Comment: @EdwinStoteler Thanks for input. Any sample source code ?

Comment: OneLogin example has many security flaws we had to fix. Check this lib instead: https://github.com/jitbit/AspNetSaml (I'm affiliated - contributor)

Answer (score 1):

You are asking about providers and there are a number of SaaS ones as well as on-premises such as shibboleth.

In terms of the SAML stack, refer [I need a SAML stack — now!](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/i-need-a-saml-stack-now-63d9691e2d43).